# GWT to use Eclipse Jetty instead of Mortbay

Tags: java, maven, gwt, jetty, errai

How to I make GWT use Eclipse Jetty:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-jndi</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Instead of the Mortbay Jetty:

```
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-naming</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
```

When I try to use Eclipse Jetty it throws on GWT dev run:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     at
>   org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)     at
>   org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.loadConfigurations(WebAppContext.java:837)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:417)
>     at
>   org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.gwt.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:525)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)    at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
>     at
>   org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.gwt.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:738)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)  at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)

Comment: Note: you're using JBoss Errai, which seem to depend on Mortbay Jetty.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Yes I have excluded the Mortbay; so you mean this error is not from GWT but from Errai?

Comment: You have excluded what brings the `org.mortbay.jetty` classes and Errai needs them, so the `ClassNotFoundException` is your entire fault. GWT 2.6 has switched to `org.eclipse.jetty` but not Errai (not in a released stable version at least), which still calls `org.mortbay.jetty` classes.